# How to override the angular material theme and insert my custom typography

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, angular-material2

I want to override the default Angular Material typography and input my own font, How can I do that ?

I have tried using this inside styles.scss but the theme keeps on overriding the scss class

```css
html {
     font-family: "AvertaStd", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif !important;
}
```

Comment: Which version of angular are you using ? v15-v16 or below ?

Comment: I'm using "@angular/material": "^16.1.3"

Answer (score 1):

this should work using **"@angular/material": "^16.1.3"**

```css
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@include mat.core();

// @import "assets/scss/fonts.scss";

@font-face {
    font-family: 'AvertaStd';
    src: url('assets/Averta-Standard-font/AvertaStd-Regular.ttf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Helvetica';
    src: url('assets/Helvetica-Font/Helvetica.ttf');
}

$my-typography: mat.define-typography-config(
    $font-family: '"AvertaStd", "Helvetica Neue"'
);

@include mat.typography-hierarchy($my-typography);
```